# Colorspace transformation for an image in R

Tags: r, image-processing, rgb, color-space

I want to transform the colorspace of a .TIFF file from RGB to lαβ in R. There is base package `grDevices` which allows you to change the colorspace using the function `convertColor`. This doesn't have any option for lαβ.

If there are any existing functions or libraries it'll be very helpful.

I tried the following approach, but it has different lαβ tables for each of the three colors, i.e., Red, Green, and Blue:

```
library(schemr)
HCC1_lab_r <- rgb_to_lab(HCC1[,,1], transformation = "sRGB")
```

EDIT: https://entuedu-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/bchua024_e_ntu_edu_sg/Ee74d3QJH0FGk5OivZDobx0B9qrwOaNqVx8xnCJW20uxPQ?e=SCaouY

here's the link to the image I'm trying to convert.

Comment: You asked the same question for Matlab: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75357715/changing-colorspace-in-matlab, are you attached to any of the two languages?

Comment: What is `lαβ` colour space? Probably it is easier to find yourself the formula and to implement it. Note `Lab` (with the very common CIELAB variant) is a very used colour spaces.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi yes `lαβ` is similar to `LAB`. just different ways of writing i think.

Comment: @KelSolaar yes i want to explore both the options: for MATLAB as well as RStudio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **colorspace** package to do such a conversion, as follows:

```r
library(colorspace)
rgbcol <- RGB(1, 0, 0)
as(rgbcol, "LAB")
```

## EDIT

For the updated question:

```r
# get a tiff image as a RGBA array
library(tiff)
Rlogo <- system.file("img", "Rlogo.tiff", package = "tiff")
img <- readTIFF(Rlogo)
# remove the fourth channel (A - the transparency)
img <- img[, , -4]

# convert the `img` array to LAB
library(colorspace)
img <- 
  apply(img, 1:2, function(rgb) as(RGB(rgb[1], rgb[2], rgb[3]), "LAB")@coords)
# restore the order of the dimensions
img <- aperm(img, c(2, 3, 1))
```

Comment: I tried running your code, but I got the following error while trying to run the code. The error is as presented below:
`Error in as(HCC1.1, "LAB") : 
  no method or default for coercing “Image” to “LAB”`

Comment: I loaded the tiff file differently: `library(ijtiff)
HCC1 <- read_tif("HCC1.tif", frames = "all", list_safety = "error", msg = TRUE)` but i received a different error for it. `Error in as(HCC1, "LAB") : 
  no method or default for coercing “ijtiff_img” to “LAB”`

Comment: @driver `HCC1` is not a color here...

Comment: I want to convert the colorspace of the entire image to LAB. I dont think this would be useful in that way.

Comment: @driver So you should edit your question to rephrase it, and show the expected output. I replied to the current question.

Comment: sure! edited and saved